# Gitlab requesting I create a merge request instead of pushing straight into repo

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, git-merge

I have setup a `deploy/staging` repo for a GitLab project, however, whenever I push into it (it has a DeployHQ webhook if that makes a difference?) it says the following:

```
remote:
remote: To create a merge request for deploy/staging, visit:
remote:   https://gitlab.com/USER/PROJECT/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=deploy%2Fstaging
remote:
```

What are the differences I could look into for this branch and my user/feature/master branches that just say the expected push messages with data compression/object writing status etc

Thanks

Comment: GitLab offers to create a merge request into the default branch of a repository on pushing to another branch is the usual behaviour; I could not find any documentation on this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user is getting such messages while pushing when the branch is protected.

See full details in [GitLab Documentation - Protected Branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html)

To disable the message uncheck `Project settings` > `General` > `Merge Requests` -> Option `Show link to create/view merge request when pushing from the command line`

[image: Merge request settings]
<sub>(source: [gitlab.com](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/img/merge_requests_settings.png))</sub>

See full details in [GitLab Documentation - Merge request settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/#merge-request-settings)

I don't know DeployHQ but as far as I know a GitLab Webhook can only notify and not block a push. See full details in [GitLab Documentation - Webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html).